# Ergodicity in hidden Markov models

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, ergodic-theory

Assume that we have a hidden Markov model, where we have a sequence of hidden variables $Z_1, \dots, Z_m$ which form a Markov chain. Now, at each "time point" $i$, an observation $Y_i$ is drawn from the conditional distribution given $Z_i$, i.e., $Y_i\sim F(\cdot | Z_i)$.

This leads to a sequence $(Z_1, Y_1), \dots, (Z_m, Y_m)$ which is a Markov chain. Now assume that the generation of the hidden variables $Z_1, \dots, Z_m$ ensures that $Z_1, \dots, Z_m$ is a stationary and ergodic sequence. Further, we even know that $(Z_1, Y_1), \dots, (Z_m, Y_m)$ then is an ergodic Markov chain.

My question is whether also the sequence of observations $Y_1, \dots, Y_m$ is ergodic given that both the sequence of hidden variables, as well as the joint sequence are ergodic. Papers such as [this one](http://www.jstor.org/stable/30244343?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) seem to address the opposed question whether the sequence of hidden variables is ergodic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem 1 of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030441499290141C) gives an answer for finite state spaces, and has been generalized later.